# Prediction from VECM in R using external forecasts of regressors

Tags: time-series, forecasting, cointegration, stationarity, vector-error-correction-model

I have the historical dataset containing numerical variables `GDP`, `HPA`, `FX` and `Y` - I am interested in predicting `Y` given some future values of `GDP`, `HPA` and `FX`.

Some variables are non-stationary as per the `adf.test`. So, I implementd a VECM framework for modeling cointegration in these 4 variables; I used

```
result = VECM(data, lag = 3, r = 1)
```

under "tsDyn" package and got an output showing that cointegration relationship does exist between these 4 variables. I also got the single cointegrating vector (r = 1) here.

My question is: How do I get predictions of `Y` given *externally-generated* future values of the other variables (for say, upcoming 10 time points), using this result programmatically?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use the `newdata` argument of the `predict` method. Note that if you have a VECM with three lags, lags in [tsDyn](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tsDyn) refer to lags of the differenced variables (as opposed to package urca/vars), and hence correspond to 4 lags of the original series.

```
library(tsDyn)

data(barry)
newDat <- tail(as.data.frame(barry),4)

vecm.eg <-VECM(barry, lag=3)

predict(vecm.eg, newdata=newDat, n.ahead=2)
```

Gives:

```
      dolcan   cpiUSA   cpiCAN
325 1.478036 110.5513 107.0424
326 1.481846 110.6971 107.1236
```

To make sure we got the right result, I gave as external data the last values of the same series, so this should correspond to the prediction with *internal* data:

```
predict(vecm.eg,  n.ahead=2)
      dolcan   cpiUSA   cpiCAN
325 1.478036 110.5513 107.0424
326 1.481846 110.6971 107.1236
```

Yes, is the same!

Comment: Hello Matifou, Thanks for the explanation. Using your example in my context, I'll input the future values of the variables, cpiUSA and cpiCAN as newdata, and I'll need to get the corresponding forecasts for the 'dependent' variable dolcan. Is this what predict() is doing?